# New line character seemingly coming from nothing

Tags: c++, cout, ofstream

```
for(int x = 4999; x >= 0; x--)
{
    outFile <<left<<setw(9)<< arr[x].Rank << "\t";
    outFile <<setw(6)<< arr[x].id << "\t";
    outFile << setw(37) << arr[x].names << "\t";
    outFile <<  arr[x].pointSum << "\r\n";

}

    for(int x = 4999; x >= 0; x--)
{
    outFile <<left<<setw(9)<< arr[x].Rank << "\t";
    //outFile <<setw(6)<< arr[x].id << "\t";
    outFile << setw(37) << arr[x].names << "\t";
    outFile <<  arr[x].pointSum << "\r\n";

}
```

The first loop outputs this on all of its lines:

> 275
>
> 160760     lcucujuyeikljuikg HighSchool           11

The second one outputs this:

> 275        lcucujuyeikljuikg HighSchool           11

For some reason getting rid of that one line somehow gets rid of a new line character. What could be causing this? I am at a complete loss here. I get the same results from cout as well

Comment: There must be a newline at the beginning of `arr[x].id`.

Comment: My bet is that `arr[x].id` has a newline character in its value.

Comment: What do you see when you examine the value of `arr[x].id` in the debugger?

Comment: Cannot [reproduce](https://ideone.com/DJjq9c)

Comment: yeah. there was a /n in arr[x].id so i made it an int. Thanks